# how to get an event id in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql, json

i have a sql script that tell me the event id when an event start,when i get that event id i can run a sql script to stop that specific event,now i need to get the event id in jquery/javascript..
here is my whole program
sql:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDowntimeEventStartByMachineName]
(
@MachineName varchar(255),
@CategoryName varchar(50),
@StartTime datetime,
@Comments varchar(100) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DepartmentId INT;

SELECT TOP 1
    @DepartmentId = CS.DepartmentId 
FROM ComputerStations AS CS
--WHERE (CS.IPAddress = @MachineName)or(CS.DnsHostName = @MachineName);
WHERE (@MachineName in (CS.IPAddress, CS.DnsHostName));


SET @StartTime = COALESCE(@StartTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO DowntimeEvent
(
DepartmentId,
CategoryName,
StartTime,
EndTime,
Comments
)
OUTPUT
    inserted.EventId,inserted.DepartmentId,inserted.CategoryName,inserted.StartTime,inserted.EndTime,inserted.Comments
VALUES
(@DepartmentId,@CategoryName,@StartTime,NULL,@Comments)

--SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('HESTOTESTINNG.dbo.DowntimeEvent') AS EventId;
END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDowntimeEventEnd]
(
@EventId int,
@EndTime datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Eid BIGINT = ( SELECT @EventId as EventId 
FROM DowntimeEvent AS DE
WHERE 
(
(EventId = @EventId)
AND
(EndTime IS NULL)
)
)
IF (@Eid IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
UPDATE DowntimeEvent
SET EndTime = COALESCE(@EndTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

WHERE
(
(EventId = @EventId)
AND
(EndTime IS NULL)
)
END
SELECT @Eid AS EventId
END
```

json page:
start of event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Hesto.SQL;
using Hesto;


public partial class services_json_DownTimeStartByMachineName : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        nvc.AddFromQueryString(Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("MachineName", Request.UserHostAddress, Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("CategoryName","NULL",Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("StartTime",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("Comments", "NULL", Request.QueryString);

        StoredProcedureCaller spc = new StoredProcedureCaller();
        spc.Execute(Request.QueryString, Resources.StoredProcedureDefinitions.DownTimeStartTimeByMachineName, Resources.ConnectionStrings.HESTOTESTING);

        Response.Write(spc.ToString("json"));
    }
}
```

stop of event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Hesto.SQL;
using Hesto;

public partial class services_json_DownTimeStop : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        nvc.AddFromQueryString(Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("EventId","", Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("EndTime", DateTime.Now.ToString(), Request.QueryString);

        StoredProcedureCaller spc = new StoredProcedureCaller();
        spc.Execute(nvc, Resources.StoredProcedureDefinitions.DownTimeStopEvent, Resources.ConnectionStrings.HESTOTESTING);

        Response.Write(spc.ToString("json"));
    }
}
```

javascript and jquery

```
function GetUserData() {
        var IPAddress = $('#IPAddress').text();
        (IPAddress == '' ? null : 'ipaddress=' + IPAddress)

        var Category = $('#categories').val();
        var ExtraData = $('#txtcomment').val();

        return {
          MachineName: IPAddress
        , CategoryName: Category
        , Comments: ExtraData
        }
    }
```

here i need to get the event id
    function GetEventId() {
        return
        {
             EventId: ''
             EndTime: '2014-04-22T08:00:00'
        }
    }

Comment: What event id ur talking..??? are u talking about the button on which you will click are the last insert id or update id..?

Comment: The last event id inserted

Comment: ok.. are you making an ajax call...??

Comment: function GetEventId() {
    return
    {
         EventId: ''
         EndTime: '2014-04-22T08:00:00'
    }
}

Comment: yes i am making an ajax call

Comment: here's the ajax call code: function DownTimeStop(data) {
    Hesto.Ajax.Get({
        query: ADD_DOWNTIME_STOP
        , data: Hesto.Ajax.BuildQueryString(data)
        , success: ShowData
        , error: Hesto.Ajax.ErrorHandler
    });
}

Comment: Normally in php I pass the last insert id in json format i.e. echo json_encode($last_insert_id);
and in my javascript file I write this code
$.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:my_url,
   data:{
     data:data //which I want to send
   },
   dataType:'json', 
   success:function(val){
         alert(val); // This will alert my last insert id... 
   }
})

Comment: I use dataType:'json' to get the data I want... If I want more details in javascript then I pass an array in json_encode() function i.e. in php.. and then I use $.each to get the data..

Comment: okay will try to use dataTpye:'json'

Comment: its dataType:'json' not dataTpye:'json'

Comment: i tried that still a person has to enter in the event id in the json call in order to stop a event.Okay when an event start
a table with a  stop button is created in javascript,what i what is when the user clicks the stop button it should stop the event and write the stoptime i.e current time that the event stop at in sql and displays the time is aspx page

Comment: I am still not getting your question... You said you want the event id in jquery/javascript.. is your event id the last insert id or the current time..??

Comment: it could be any event id first middle or last the current time represent what time that specific event id stopped

Comment: OK.. are you getting the current time in javascript i.e. ajax success function..??

Comment: yes here is the page http://10.19.13.68/services/json/DownTimeStop.aspx?eventid=7..by me putting in the event id i do get the current time written into sql database table

Comment: ok.. so you jst want to display the current time in some div right..? if yes then you can create a div say <div id="current_time"></div> and then in your ajax success add $('#current_time').text(val); // val I am getting is in success function i.e. success:function(val){}

Comment: I am not able to open the link... :(

Comment: the link cannot be open from outside source cos am running the application from an internal net work,but will try what you have suggested

Comment: sure... Do let me know..

Comment: It does work the only problem now,is how to get the event id that is stored in sql?

Comment: Can you please look at my procedure AddDowntimeEventEnd,i just need to get the event id where 1st or last from the procedure AddDowntimeEventStartByMachineName,and oh my Eventid column is an identity column